# Wrong growth rate

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

[image: you can see the value of growth when -1 divided 0]

I'm currently working on calculating the growth rate in Power BI using DAX programming, but I've hit a snag. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with -1 divided by zero and it's giving me an incorrect calculation. I was wondering if anyone could lend a hand and help me fix this error. Thanks in advance!

Code: Sales growth = CALCULATE([2024]-[2023])/[2023]

Comment: You have hidden precision in those numbers. If you hadn't, the fourth row should read / round to -42.87%. I.e., the math isn't broken, your input is not quite what you're seeing. You might be looking at something like 0.49 for 2023 or -0.51 for 2024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using divide function instead:

```
Sales growth = ROUND([2024]-[2023],0)/ROUND([2023],0)
```

Comment: "Thank you, but nothing has changed."

Comment: What is your expected result? I'll update now.

Comment: It must be an infinite value. You can check the image that I have shared with the question.

Comment: OK, I'll  update once more. This looks like a precision issue.